# I'm not understanding this filter() method in Javascript that removes duplicates.

Tags: javascript

I don't quite get what's happening in this function.

```
    function unique(array) {
      return array.filter(function(a){
        return !this[a] ? this[a] = true : false;
      }, {});
    }
```

This function will remove duplicates from an array, and I understand the the 'a' parameter is representing each element in the array, but I have two questions:

1. Is 'this' representing 'array'? If so, if I had an array that was:

   ```
   let array = [1,2,3,400,5];
   ```

   array[400] would be undefined, so my guess doesn't seem right.
2. What is the empty object '{}' at the end?

Comment: where `{}` is act as `this`  and based on  checking the property previously defined or not filtering it

Comment: [MDN `filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter): _“`arr.filter(callback[, thisArg])` — `thisArg`: Optional. Value to use as **`this`** when executing `callback`.”_. Pretty obvious. Then you just need to know what happens when `!this[a] ? this[a] = true : false` gets executed. You can test it yourself by [using your console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.filter()` function takes an optional second argument; in this case that argument is `{}`, an empty object. That value is used as the value of `this` on each call to the callback function. The value of `this` then is *not* a reference to the array itself.

Thus that code is using that object to keep track of what values have been seen in the array so far. The callback checks to see whether the key has not been added yet to the object. If not, it's added with value `true`, and `true` is returned. Otherwise, when the key is already in the object, the callback returns `false`. So for the second and subsequent occurrences of some repeated value in the array, the `.filter()` function will not include it in the result.

Note that this technique only works well when the array contains things that convert "nicely" to strings, because property names must be strings. A variation on that could use a Set instance (in ES2015 environments) to surmount that limitation:

```
function unique2015(array) {
  return array.filter(function(a){
    return !this.has(a) ? this.add(a) : false;
  }, new Set());
}
```

*edit* — that can actually be a lot simpler with ES2015:

```
function unique2015(array) {
  return Array.from(new Set(array).values());
}
```

The Set constructor basically does all the work.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time for such a clear and concise explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The code uses `{}`, which is passed as the `this` value, as a hash in which it stores the visited elements. If the current element is not in the hash it is included in the returned array, if it's already in the hash it's filtered out.

However, it has some important problems:

- `{}` already has some properties, inherited from `Object.prototype`

  ```js
  function unique(array) {
    return array.filter(function(a){
      return !this[a] ? this[a] = true : false;
    }, {});
  }
  console.log(unique(['hasOwnProperty'])); // [] Oops!
  ```
- If your array contains values which are not strings or symbols, they will be coerced to strings

  ```js
  function unique(array) {
    return array.filter(function(a){
      return !this[a] ? this[a] = true : false;
    }, {});
  }
  console.log(unique([ {a:1}, {b:2} ])); // [ {a:1} ] Oops!
  ```

Comment: Thank you. In your second example, is the function seeing the second element as a duplicate?

Comment: @MatthewMoon Both `{a:1}` and `{b:2}` are coerced to `"[object Object]"`, that's why the second is removed as a "duplicate".

Answer (score 1):

The `{}` is an empty object with all prototypes.

If you make a check with

```js
if ({}.toString) {
    console.log('toString exists.');
}
```

then you get `true` and the then part get executed.

This may not the behaviour, you want, because you have strings, which could be the string, you need, but it does not behave like the prototype.

Then, you need an object without any prototypes. This could be achieved with

```js
var emptyObject = Object.create(null);

console.log(emptyObject.toString); // undefined
```

Comment: This is a good point and can be an important consideration in some circumstances.. ;)